# Fiona throws KeyError when attempting to read a shapefile

Tags: shapefile, fiona, geopandas

I'm attempting to read the `AADT_2014.shp` file from the [New York State Department of Transportation average traffic data](https://www.dot.ny.gov/tdv) ([`TDV_Shapefile_AADT_2014.zip`](https://www.dot.ny.gov/divisions/engineering/applications/traffic-data-viewer/traffic-data-viewer-repository/TDV_Shapefile_AADT_2014.zip) specifically through `fiona` (by way of `geopandas`). Here's the equivalent minimum working example:

```
import fiona
import io
import zipfile
import requests

r = requests.get("https://www.dot.ny.gov/divisions/engineering/applications/traffic-data-viewer/traffic-data-viewer-repository/TDV_Shapefile_AADT_2014.zip", 
                 verify=False)
zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(r.content), 'r').extractall()
for feature in fiona.open("AADT_2014.shp"):
    print(feature)
```

`geopandas` wraps a simple `fiona` call for reading this data in. It successfully works out localizing the similar [NYC Lion dataset](https://wfs.gc.cuny.edu/SRomalewski/NYCLION/nyclion_15c.zip), for example.

But with this data `fiona` raised a `KeyError`:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-d9cf07a334ea> in <module>()
      1 import geopandas as gpd
----> 2 aadt = gpd.read_file("../data/aadt/AADT_2014.shp")

/Users/Honors/anaconda/envs/nyc-traffic-model/lib/python3.5/site-packages/geopandas/io/file.py in read_file(filename, **kwargs)
     26         else:
     27             f_filt = f
---> 28         gdf = GeoDataFrame.from_features(f, crs=crs)
     29 
     30     return gdf

/Users/Honors/anaconda/envs/nyc-traffic-model/lib/python3.5/site-packages/geopandas/geodataframe.py in from_features(cls, features, crs)
    185         """
    186         rows = []
--> 187         for f in features:
    188             if hasattr(f, "__geo_interface__"):
    189                 f = f.__geo_interface__

fiona/ogrext.pyx in fiona.ogrext.Iterator.__next__ (fiona/ogrext.c:19524)()

fiona/ogrext.pyx in fiona.ogrext.FeatureBuilder.build (fiona/ogrext.c:4795)()

fiona/_geometry.pyx in fiona._geometry.GeomBuilder.build (fiona/_geometry.c:3406)()

KeyError: 2002
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not that simple. The shapefile seems corrupted with many records without geometry.
You can see it using osgeo.ogr:

```py
from osgeo import ogr
import json
reader = ogr.Open("AADT_2014.shp")
layer = reader.GetLayer()
layer.GetFeatureCount()
54955
one = layer.GetFeature(0)
json.loads(a.ExportToJson())
{u'geometry': {u'type': u'LineString', u'coordinates': [[590128.580000001, 4520399.800000003, -1.3124998304e-05], [590125.9100000001, 4520411.200000001, 0.007286875001682], [590126.2800000012, 4520415.650000002, 0.010086875001889], [590127.9700000007, 4520422.22, 0.014286875001744], [590154.9900000021, 4520488.390000004, 0.058986875001665], [590158.330000001, 4520498.2, 0.06548687500208], [590208.5700000012, 4520617.61, 0.146386875001781], [590238.97, 4520690.15, 0.195486875001734], [590267.54, 4520760.33, 0.242886875001659], [590337.6700000009, 4520928.4, 0.356586875002904], [590393.200000002, 4521062.64, 0.447386875001712], [590446.2000000002, 4521190.080000002, 0.533586875001674], [590453.9900000021, 4521208.05, 0.545786875001795], [590494.0100000007, 4521300.69, 0.608886875001645], [590513.5199999996, 4521346.230000004, 0.639786875001619], [590530.9300000016, 4521384.3, 0.665986875001636], [590563.5700000012, 4521465.859999998, 0.720886875001725], [590601.5600000005, 4521558.26, 0.78328687500175], [590605.4500000002, 4521570.96, 0.791586875001713], [590608.7599999998, 4521596.87, 0.807886875001714], [590615.83, 4521659.91, 0.847486875002005], [590618.5099999998, 4521675.04, 0.857086875002778], [590623.3800000008, 4521690.530000001, 0.867186875001607], [590638.9800000023, 4521717.930000002, 0.886886875001665], [590698.8499999996, 4521827.139999999, 0.964686875001689], [590708.7800000003, 4521843.020000003, 0.976386875001708], [590716.580000001, 4521859.440000003, 0.987786875002712], [590723.5499999998, 4521875.510000002, 0.998686875001795], [590725.5999999996, 4521887.080000002, 1.006086875001756], [590730.5000000019, 4521927.89, 1.031786875001671], [590733.6399999997, 4521960.790000003, 1.052386875001957], [590738.2100000009, 4522020.8, 1.089986875001614]]}, u'type': u'Feature', u'properties': {u'AADT_YEAR': u'2014', u'TDV_ROUTE': u'OGDEN AVE', u'OBJECTID': 1, u'AADT_TYPE': u'FORECAST', u'SPEED_TDV': u'http://ftp.dot.ny.gov/tdv/YR2014/nospeed.pdf', u'LEN': 1.09, u'EP': 1.09, u'MUNI': u'City of Bronx', u'LOC_ERROR': u'NO ERROR', u'BMP': 0.0, u'ROADWAYTYP': u'Road', u'GISID': 25594001, u'AADT': u'7847', u'EndDesc': u'UNIVERSITY AVE', u'Shape_Leng': 1744.8616779, u'BegDesc': u'JEROME AVE', u'CLASS_TDV': u'http://ftp.dot.ny.gov/tdv/YR2014/noclass.pdf', u'VOL_TDV': u'http://ftp.dot.ny.gov/tdv/YR2011/R11/01_Bronx/01_2030.pdf', u'RC_ID': u'01_2030', u'DATA_TYPE': u'VOLUME', u'CC_ID': None}, u'id': 0}
# and
end  = layer.GetFeature(54954) # last record
json.loads(end.ExportToJson())
{u'geometry': None, u'type': u'Feature', u'properties': {u'AADT_YEAR': u'2014', u'TDV_ROUTE': u'NORRIS', u'OBJECTID': 54955, u'AADT_TYPE': u'FORECAST', u'SPEED_TDV': u'http://ftp.dot.ny.gov/tdv/YR2014/nospeed.pdf', u'LEN': 0.13, u'EP': 0.13, u'MUNI': u'Town of Candor', u'LOC_ERROR': u'ROUTE NOT FOUND', u'BMP': 0.0, u'ROADWAYTYP': u'Road', u'GISID': 17361601, u'AADT': u'26', u'EndDesc': u'DEAD END', u'Shape_Leng': 0.0, u'BegDesc': u'PROSPECT VALLE', u'CLASS_TDV': u'http://ftp.dot.ny.gov/tdv/YR2014/noclass.pdf', u'VOL_TDV': u'http://ftp.dot.ny.gov/tdv/YR2009/R09/97_Tioga/97_6191.pdf', u'RC_ID': u'97_6191', u'DATA_TYPE': u'VOLUME', u'CC_ID': None}, u'id': 54954}
```

And if I try a Python generator (as in Fiona)

```py
def records(file):  
    # generator 
    reader = ogr.Open(file)
    layer = reader.GetLayer()
    for i in range(layer.GetFeatureCount()):
        feature = layer.GetFeature(i)
        yield json.loads(feature.ExportToJson())
features = records("AADT_2014.shp")
feature_id = [feature['id'] for feature in features if not feature['geometry']]
len(feature_id)
19761 # there are 19761 records without geometry
```

The importation of the shapefile in GRASS GIS ([v.in.ogr](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/v.in.ogr.html)) gives the same result

> Importing 54955 features (OGR layer )...
>   WARNING: 19761 features without geometry skipped

That does not work with Fiona

```py
import fiona
reader = fiona.open("AADT_2014.shp")
feature_id = [feature['id'] for feature in reader if not feature['geometry']]
Traceback (most recent call last):
....
KeyError: 2002
```

But if I "clean" the shapefile with `ogr2ogr AADT_2014_fixed.shp AADT_2014.shp` ([ogr2ogr every Shapefile](http://spatiallyadjusted.com/ogr2ogr-every-shapefile/)), it works with empty geometries:

```py
import fiona
reader = fiona.open("AADT_2014_fixed.shp")
len(reader)
54955
feature_id = [feature['id'] for feature in reader if not feature['geometry']]
len(feature_id)
19761
features = list(reader)
features[54954]
{'geometry': None, 'type': 'Feature', 'id': '54954', 'properties': OrderedDict([(u'OBJECTID', 54955), (u'BegDesc', u'PROSPECT VALLE'), (u'EndDesc', u'DEAD END'), (u'RC_ID', u'97_6191'), (u'GISID', 17361601), (u'BMP', 0.0), (u'EP', 0.13), (u'LEN', 0.13), (u'LOC_ERROR', u'ROUTE NOT FOUND'), (u'TDV_ROUTE', u'NORRIS'), (u'MUNI', u'Town of Candor'), (u'AADT_TYPE', u'FORECAST'), (u'AADT_YEAR', u'2014'), (u'DATA_TYPE', u'VOLUME'), (u'VOL_TDV', u'http://ftp.dot.ny.gov/tdv/YR2009/R09/97_Tioga/97_6191.pdf'), (u'CLASS_TDV', u'http://ftp.dot.ny.gov/tdv/YR2014/noclass.pdf'), (u'SPEED_TDV', u'http://ftp.dot.ny.gov/tdv/YR2014/nospeed.pdf'), (u'CC_ID', None), (u'ROADWAYTYP', u'Road'), (u'Shape_Leng', 0.0), (u'AADT', u'26')])}
```

If I use the "topological clean" result of GRASS GIS ([v.out.ogr](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/v.out.ogr.html), Grass eliminate all the redundant geometries and the records without geometries)

```py
import fiona
reader = fiona.open("grass_aadt.shp")
len(reader)
35509
feature_id = [feature['id'] for feature in reader if not feature['geometry']]
len(feature_id)
0
```

Thus the original shapefiles can be read

- with QGIS, OpenJUMP (signalling errors), GRASS GIS (correcting errors) but not gvSIG for example
- with  `ogrinfo -al  AADT_2014.shp` (list of features)
- with python and osgeo.ogr
- with [pyshp (shapefile)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyshp/1.2.10) (pure Python module), with errors with records without geometry

```py
 import shapefile
 reader = shapefile.Reader("AADT_2014.shp")
 features = list(reader.iterShapes())
 feature_id = [feature for feature in a if not feature.m]
 len(feature_id)
 19761
 # but
 features[0].points
 [(590128.580000001, 4520399.800000003), (590125.9100000001, 4520411.200000001), (590126.2800000012, 4520415.650000002), (590127.9700000007, 4520422.220000001), (590154.9900000021, 4520488.390000004), (590158.330000001, 4520498.199999999), (590208.5700000012, 4520617.609999999), (590238.9699999997, 4520690.15), (590267.54, 4520760.33), (590337.6700000009, 4520928.4), (590393.200000002, 4521062.640000001), (590446.2000000002, 4521190.080000002), (590453.9900000021, 4521208.050000001), (590494.0100000007, 4521300.6899999995), (590513.5199999996, 4521346.230000004), (590530.9300000016, 4521384.300000001), (590563.5700000012, 4521465.859999998), (590601.5600000005, 4521558.26), (590605.4500000002, 4521570.960000001), (590608.7599999998, 4521596.869999999), (590615.8300000001, 4521659.91), (590618.5099999998, 4521675.039999999), (590623.3800000008, 4521690.530000001), (590638.9800000023, 4521717.930000002), (590698.8499999996, 4521827.139999999), (590708.7800000003, 4521843.020000003), (590716.580000001, 4521859.440000003), (590723.5499999998, 4521875.510000002), (590725.5999999996, 4521887.080000002), (590730.5000000019, 4521927.890000001), (590733.6399999997, 4521960.790000003), (590738.2100000009, 4522020.800000001)]
 features[0].__geo_interface__  
{'type': 'LineString', 'coordinates': ((590128.580000001, 4520399.800000003), (590125.9100000001, 4520411.200000001), (590126.2800000012, 4520415.650000002), (590127.9700000007, 4520422.220000001), (590154.9900000021, 4520488.390000004), (590158.330000001, 4520498.199999999), (590208.5700000012, 4520617.609999999), (590238.9699999997, 4520690.15), (590267.54, 4520760.33), (590337.6700000009, 4520928.4), (590393.200000002, 4521062.640000001), (590446.2000000002, 4521190.080000002), (590453.9900000021, 4521208.050000001), (590494.0100000007, 4521300.6899999995), (590513.5199999996, 4521346.230000004), (590530.9300000016, 4521384.300000001), (590563.5700000012, 4521465.859999998), (590601.5600000005, 4521558.26), (590605.4500000002, 4521570.960000001), (590608.7599999998, 4521596.869999999), (590615.8300000001, 4521659.91), (590618.5099999998, 4521675.039999999), (590623.3800000008, 4521690.530000001), (590638.9800000023, 4521717.930000002), (590698.8499999996, 4521827.139999999), (590708.7800000003, 4521843.020000003), (590716.580000001, 4521859.440000003), (590723.5499999998, 4521875.510000002), (590725.5999999996, 4521887.080000002), (590730.5000000019, 4521927.890000001), (590733.6399999997, 4521960.790000003), (590738.2100000009, 4522020.800000001))}
# and
features[54954].points
[]
features[54954].__geo_interface__  
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
AttributeError: _Shape instance has no attribute 'parts'
```

Answer (score 2):

This appears to perhaps be a core library issue, as the file opens without incident on QGIS. I've [raised a GitHub issue](https://github.com/Toblerity/Fiona/issues/384) for the matter.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the problem. See https://github.com/Toblerity/Fiona/issues/384#issuecomment-251060434.