# geopandas read_file breaks in fiona open()

Tags: python, fiona, geopandas

I am trying to read-in a shp file and can't seem to do it with the geopandas version 0.2.1. Here is the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-b4165d16b7f3> in <module>()
----> 1 gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file('D:/NHDPlusV21/NHDPlusMS/NHDPlus06/NHDSnapshot/Hydrography/NHDFlowline.shp')

C:\Users\Rdebbout\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\envs\nusc\lib\site-packages\geopandas\geodataframe.pyc in from_file(cls, filename, **kwargs)
    173 
    174         """
--> 175         return geopandas.io.file.read_file(filename, **kwargs)
    176 
    177     @classmethod

C:\Users\Rdebbout\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\envs\nusc\lib\site-packages\geopandas\io\file.pyc in read_file(filename, **kwargs)
     26         else:
     27             f_filt = f
---> 28         gdf = GeoDataFrame.from_features(f, crs=crs)
     29 
     30     return gdf

C:\Users\Rdebbout\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\envs\nusc\lib\site-packages\geopandas\geodataframe.pyc in from_features(cls, features, crs)
    185         """
    186         rows = []
--> 187         for f in features:
    188             if hasattr(f, "__geo_interface__"):
    189                 f = f.__geo_interface__

fiona\ogrext.pyx in fiona.ogrext.Iterator.__next__ (fiona/ogrext.c:20633)()

fiona\ogrext.pyx in fiona.ogrext.FeatureBuilder.build (fiona/ogrext.c:5188)()

fiona\_geometry.pyx in fiona._geometry.GeomBuilder.build (fiona/_geometry.c:3556)()

KeyError: 3002L
```

I have looked at the issue [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/212738/fiona-throws-keyerror-when-attempting-to-read-a-shapefile) and checked that 'id' 3002 exists, which it does as well as use Shapely to validate all of the geometries in the file.

I have another environment with the same versions of geopandas and a different version of fiona(1.5.1) that does work to load in the shp file, the one that doesn't work has fiona (1.7.0). Is it safe to say that this is a package issue with all this info? or am i missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Does the issue present its self with other shapefiles too or just this one? I'm running geopandas 2.1.0 and fiona 1.7.3 and can't reproduce the issue w/ any files I have.  Maybe you should try updating fiona?

I like to run this nifty little script every so often.  It takes a little while to run but it will update every package you have installed.

```
import pip
from subprocess import call

for dist in pip.get_installed_distributions():
    call("pip install --upgrade " + dist.project_name, shell=True)
    print (dist.project_name)
```